# Not Able to Import JdbcTemplate Class in STS

Tags: java, spring

What am I doing wrong that I'm not able to import org.springframework.jdbc and MANY other packages when I put this artifact in my pom.xml file?

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
 <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

When I put `private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;` in my class, I'm not able to import the above package and I noticed that I missing many other packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JDBC package is part of [spring-jdbc](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc). Not spring-context.

The Spring framework looks like a giant set of clases, but it's actually split into various libraries: spring-context, spring-jdbc, spring-orm, etc. You need to declare the dependencies to the ones you want.

Comment: Can you please tell me where do go to know where these libraries are? I couldn't figure this out for the anything. Thanks.

Comment: @JBNizet...I just realized that was a link to the maven site. THANKS!